# GitLab (6.6.5) Omnibus configuration for PostgreSQL

Tags: gitlab

```
ls -la /etc/gitlab/
-rwxrwxrwx   1 git  git  gitlab.rb

cat /etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb 

# Disable the built-in Postgres
  postgresql['enable'] = false

# Fill in the values for database.yml
  gitlab_rails['db_adapter'] = 'postgresql'
  gitlab_rails['db_encoding'] = 'unicode'
  gitlab_rails['db_database'] = 'gitlab_db_name'
  gitlab_rails['db_pool'] = 10
  gitlab_rails['db_host'] = 'aws-RDShost.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com'
  gitlab_rails['db_port'] = 5432
  gitlab_rails['db_username'] = "gitlab_user"
  gitlab_rails['db_password'] = 'mypass'
```

Now the problem is that 6.6.5 gitlab is not overwriting the database.rb file sitting at /var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/etc/database.rb

Full error stack:

Compiling Cookbooks...

Recipe: gitlab::default

```
* directory[/etc/gitlab] action create
  - change owner from 'git' to 'root'
  - change group from 'git' to 'root'

[2015-04-16T20:32:04+00:00] WARN: Cloning resource attributes for directory[/var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/etc] from prior resource (CHEF-3694)

[2015-04-16T20:32:04+00:00] WARN: Previous directory[/var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/etc]: /opt/gitlab/embedded/cookbooks/gitlab/recipes/gitlab-rails.rb:36:in `block in from_file'

[2015-04-16T20:32:04+00:00] WARN: Current  directory[/var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/etc]: /opt/gitlab/embedded/cookbooks/gitlab/definitions/unicorn_config.rb:21:in `block in from_file'

[2015-04-16T20:32:04+00:00] WARN: Cloning resource attributes for service[unicorn] from prior resource (CHEF-3694)

[2015-04-16T20:32:04+00:00] WARN: Previous service[unicorn]: /opt/gitlab/embedded/cookbooks/gitlab/recipes/default.rb:58:in `block in from_file'

[2015-04-16T20:32:04+00:00] WARN: Current  service[unicorn]: /opt/gitlab/embedded/cookbooks/runit/definitions/runit_service.rb:173:in `block in from_file'

[2015-04-16T20:32:04+00:00] WARN: Cloning resource attributes for service[sidekiq] from prior resource (CHEF-3694)

[2015-04-16T20:32:04+00:00] WARN: Previous service[sidekiq]: /opt/gitlab/embedded/cookbooks/gitlab/recipes/default.rb:58:in `block in from_file'

[2015-04-16T20:32:04+00:00] WARN: Current  service[sidekiq]: /opt/gitlab/embedded/cookbooks/runit/definitions/runit_service.rb:173:in `block in from_file'
```

Recipe: gitlab::postgresql_disable

```
* link[/opt/gitlab/service/postgresql] action delete (up to date)
```

Recipe: gitlab::database_migrations

```
* execute[initialize database] action nothing (skipped due to action :nothing)
* execute[chown git:git /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/db/schema.rb] action run
    - execute chown git:git /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/db/schema.rb
* execute[migrate database] action run
Error executing action `run` on resource 'execute[migrate database]'
Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed

Expected process to exit with [0], but received '1'
    Begin output of /opt/gitlab/bin/gitlab-rake db:migrate

STDOUT: 
STDERR: rake aborted!
could not connect to server: Connection refused
Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

Comment: Is there a reason you're using such an outdated version of GitLab? They're on 7.9.4 right now.

Comment: Actually I am in the middle of migration and upgrade. Plan is to move this server to the new VPC and then upgrade. I initially tried to start 7.9.2, but i was having much problem with connecting to the database.